# Error al hacer un insert into en php con pdo en fk : Integrity constraint violation

Tags: php, sql, pdo

estoy intentando hacer un insert into en la tabla t_contactos, para añadir un contacto nuevo el cual pertenece a una categoría, este ya tiene un usuario asignado, la cosa está en que no puedo hacer el agregado del contacto sin indicarle el usuario creado que es el de acceso al login.
¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***form***

```
   <?php 
    include 'config/conexion.php';
    $sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT id_categoria,nombre FROM t_categorias");
    $sentencia->execute();
    $datos = $sentencia->fetchAll();
    
    //print_r($t_categorias);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Insertar Contactos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 class="insertar">Insertar Contactos</h3>
        <form method="POST" action="crud/tabla_contactos/insertarProceso.php">

        <label for="categorias">Categorias</label>
        <select name="categoriaSelect">
        <?php foreach($datos as $valores) : 
            echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_categoria'].'">'.$valores['nombre'].'</option>';
         endforeach; ?>
        </select><br>

            <input type="hidden" name="id_usuarios">
            
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre">

            <label for="apellido_1">Apellido 1.</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_1">

            <label for="apellido_2">Apellido 2.</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_2">

            <label for="nota_parcial">Teléfono</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email">

            <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Insertar Contacto">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***el proceso***

```
<?php 
    include '../../config/Conexion.php';
    //print_r($_POST);
    if(!isset($_POST['oculto'])){
        exit();
    }

    try {
        $selectCategoria = $_POST['categoriaSelect'];
        $id_usuarios = $_POST['id_usuarios'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido_1 = $_POST['apellido_1'];
        $apellido_2 = $_POST['apellido_2'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $sentencia_insertar = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO t_contactos (id_categoria,id_usuarios,nombre,apellido_1,apellido_2,telefono,email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        $resultado = $sentencia_insertar->execute([$selectCategoria,$id_usuarios,$nombre,$apellido_1,$apellido_2,$telefono,$email]);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error al ejecutar el insert <br>".$e->getMessage();
    }
    /*INSERT INTO `t_contactos` 
    (`id_contactos`, `id_categoria`, `id_usuarios`, `nombre`, `apellido_1`, `apellido_2`, `telefono`, `email`, `fecha_de_inserccion`) 
    VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', current_timestamp());*/
    /*if($resultado === true){
        header('Location: ../verificado/insertar_ok.php');
    }else{
        header('Location: ../verificado/insertar_error.php');
    }*/
```

***El error***

Error al ejecutar el insert
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`agenda`.`t_contactos`, CONSTRAINT `t_contactos_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuarios`) REFERENCES `t_usuarios` (`id_usuarios`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dices que ya tiene un usuario asignado pero en tu INSERT no se ve en ninguna parte que incluyas un id_usuario en la inserción. ¿A qué te refieres con que el usuario está asignado?

Comment: hola Alfabravo me referia a este te pego imagen

Comment: Supongo que hay una sesión ¿No puedes obtener `id_usuarios` a partir ahí?

Comment: si hay una sesión activa de ese usuario, si lo inserto desde el formulario da ese error

Comment: la consulta normal sería esta -> INSERT INTO `t_contactos` 
    (`id_contactos`, `id_categoria`, `id_usuarios`, `nombre`, `apellido_1`, `apellido_2`, `telefono`, `email`, `fecha_de_inserccion`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1', 'david', 'm', 'm', '33333333', 'adadsadas@gmail.com', current_timestamp());
Pero el valor que está en la tercera posición que es el usuario de sesión y no se como recogerlo en el proceso.

Comment: Pues al iniciar sesión se guardarán cosas en $_SESSION, supondría uno. Y en alguna parte se hará un session_start(), supongo también.

Comment: mañana lo reviso creo que se cómo hacerlo, tengo el pc apagado que mañana madrugo gracias si lo resuelvo mañana por la tarde pego la respuesta :)

Comment: La pregunta me parece algo confusa, no logro entender con toda claridad qué es lo que pretendes. Por otra parte, veo una posible redundancia de datos entre `t_contactos`  y `t_usuarios`  (se repiten `nombre` y `email`). Por último, esto me suena a TRIGGER, para resolverlo a nivel de base de datos, sin necesidad de re-inventar la rueda en PHP. Es sólo una idea que me viene a la cabeza, pero vaya usted a saber, cuando el contexto no es claro es difícil determinar con certeza cual podría ser la mejor solución.

Comment: el email es del propio contacto que se añade a la agenda el otro corresponde al login de acceso